# imshow in OpenCv shows black screen

Tags: opencv, video, codec

I have created a project once and it was working properly, after reinstalling operation system, I set up the enviroment and all the components and suddenly i am not getting any output at all. My program for testing is simple:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{
VideoCapture cap("videofile.avi"); 
if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

namedWindow("Frame", 1);
for (;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    if (!cap.read(frame)) {
        cerr << "Unable to read next frame." << endl;
        cerr << "Exiting..." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    imshow("Frame", frame);
    if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}

return 0;
}
```

I have installed all necessary codecs and updated video card drivers. Still getting the same black screen.

The output looks like this:
[image: Black screen]

EDIT:

The problem appears to be only when playing .avi videos with AVC codec

Comment: The code seems ok. Try with `VideoCapture cap(0);` that will use the default camera. If it works, then you have some codec problem

Comment: @Miki It does work with camera. I will have to check my codecs again. I have installed K-Lite codec Mega though

Comment: do you have the opencv_ffmpeg dll in your PATH variable or the binary directory?

Comment: Yes I do, funny thing is I didn't need such a thing last time.

Comment: @Croolman does loading and displaying single images work? can you try to record your webcam stream to a .avi file with cv::VideoWriter and try to load that file with cv::VideoCapture? If it is a codec problem, decoding should work if encoding worked?!?

Comment: @Micka Displaying images works. I can succesfully display and record the webcam and than display the recorded file. Does it mean there has to be something wrong with my other videos I use? I can play them in VLC, I used to use them in my project with no problem.

Comment: @Croolman VLC has nearly all codecs included. Really looks like a codec problem in your OpenCV. Do you know the codec of your videos? Can you share such a video? I could try to load it in my OpenCV environment.

Comment: If the video you use is not 8bit per channel, make sure to convert each frame before trying to show it.

Comment: @Micka I can't share the video. It uses the AVC codec though. And as I said, it worked normally before.

Comment: @Croolman *before* was before reinstalling OS and OpenCV? So there are many possible error sources. If you can find a public source with a video that doesn't work, share it. Verifying that it does or doesn't work on different non-specialized systems (which your old one might have been, with special codecs or sth.) could give you another clue about the error souce.

Comment: @Micka yes, before was before reinstalling OS. It was and it is Windows 10 (64bit). I tried this http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 video, and this one doesnt work either. Seems like problem with AVC codec

Comment: I have find out that it is a problem of codec, but I am not able to resolve the problem. I can open video files with cinepack codec, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
At the end the bin folder was missing in PATH variable, so after adding new entry - **%OPENCV_DIR%\bin**, everything is working propelly.

*Clumsy solution:
get opencv_ffmpeg300.dll,    opencv_ffmpeg.dll, those can be found       right in opencv library
   - get  openh264-1.5.0-win64msvc.dll this one can be found at    [Openh264](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/releases)
   - copy all those into the working directory of the project*